# executing SQL*Plus and copying sql file

Tags: java, sqlplus

How can I execute SQL*PLUS to execute a script. The script will generate a file, and I would like to move that generated file to a directory.

This is how the process is.

In run.sh file, I give values to parameters of a bash script

```
./run.sh <schema_name> <user_name> <password> <environment>
```

These values are passed to the sql.java:

first java goes to the following directory.

```
./system_scripts
```

There java starts SQL* PLUS and executes a script (gen.ddl) by using this command:

```
sqlplus <user_name>/<password>@<environment> gen.ddl
```

This will create a result file: result.ddl

Move (not copy) that result.ddl file to. Overwrite the previous file if any:

```
 ./schema/<schema_name>/scripts
```

print a message

```
job done
```

and done.

How can I do so?
thanks in advance :-)

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Do you have a java application already that you need to modify? Do you have any code? If all you are looking to do is move a file, you should be able to just edit your shell script to move the file at the end instead of writing a whole other application.

Comment: No at this moment, I don't have a code. I am very new to java. Not only move the file, but also execute sqlplus from java.

Comment: This isn't a site where people write your entire application for you. You should instead do some google searches for java tutorials. SO is more for helping people that are stuck at a specific problem.

Comment: @Jaanna I would suggest looking at Runtime.getRuntime().exec("String command"); method in order to achieve this. It is going to be a little bit different since you need to have multiple parameters for the shell scripts.